# GWT Date Range Selection Widget

Tags: gwt, datepicker

I'm looking for a UI widget for GWT that will allow a date range to be selected, preferably disallowing future dates. Having two date pickers isn't terribly user friendly, but I haven't seen anything better out there.

One like this would be great:
https://demo.reztrip.com/

Answer (score 1):

GWT by default has no such widget. There are only few relevant libraries to explore to pick of ideas -

```
Sencha ( GWT based widgets )
Vaadin ( GWT based widgets )
SmartGWT ( GWT JSNI wrappers on js widgets )
Jquery/GwtQuery plugin - ( GWT rewrite of JQuery, You would probably need to do plugin port)
```

I have not found any third party open source libs with Serious **User Interaction Design** that stands out.

**That leaves you to design your own widget**. You can start by looking up [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/), [Google Flight](https://www.google.com/flights/) and other Google's GWT based products.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a popup for creating the interval. At first click, use is asked to choose a date and remove/hide that screen and show another screen in popup asking for second date to select an interval and once you have both the values, you can work that interval in your program